# Public routes with parameters that do not require authentication do not work in express

Tags: javascript, express

```
function jwt() {
  const { secret } = config;
  return expressJwt({ secret, algorithms: ["HS256"] }).unless({
    path: [
      // public routes that don't require authentication
      "/users/authenticate",
      "/users/create",

      "/series/getAllSeries",

      "/series/getByIdSeries/:id",
      "/series/getByStreamingService/:streamingService",
      "/series/getMonthSeries/:monthPosition/:streamingServiceName?",
    ],
  });
}
```

This routes only work with token. The exception for them to work publicly does not work

```
"/series/getByIdSeries/:id",
"/series/getByStreamingService/:streamingService",
"/series/getMonthSeries/:monthPosition/:streamingServiceName?",
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Probably parameters like `:id` are not allowed in paths in `unless`. See https://github.com/jfromaniello/express-unless#examples.